# Slider not working properly for android 4.0.3 but working for 2.3.5 ,4.1,4.2

Tags: android, slider

I am working on project which needs slider for better navigation.so, I found out slider after searching on internet.It's working cool on android 2.3.5, 4.1, 4.2 that much devices I Have.but not working properly on 4.0.3 , 4.0.4 .I have one listview in slider panel and other in my main layout.When I open slider it opens up and I can click on list of slider but when I close it n try to click on main listview in my main layout I cannot click on it.I got nothing in logcat no exception.
I have posted whole sample project code here please help me.

[slider sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldsy231nxikbx3c/example_slide-master.zip)

If I donot find the solution for this I have to change slider which will be very much complicated for me in my main project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution for issue of slider not working for 4.0.3 ,4.0.4.

The problem was I could not able to click on any list when I was openeing slider and closing it.I fixed this issue by just refreshing adapter for both list i.e list in slider and list in my main layout while opening or closing slider function.

Still don't know why it was not working for 4.0.3,4.0.4 before applying this solution though it was working for other android versions.